# Django: Date comparison and definition

Tags: django, web

I have in my views.py

```
def overdue(request):
    logged_in = request.user.is_authenticated()
    if not logged_in:
        return redirect('/sign_in')
    username = request.user.get_username()
    type = UserProfile.objects.get(username = username).type
    if type != 1:
        return redirect('/rule')

    today_date = date.today()
    books = Borrowing.objects.filter(dueDate < today_date)


    return render(request, 'books/clerk/overdue.html', {'logged_in':logged_in, 'username':username, 'type':type, 'books':books})
```

and in my models.py, I have

```
class Borrowing(models.Model):
        bid = models.ForeignKey('Borrower')
        callNumber = models.ForeignKey('Book')
        copyNo = models.ForeignKey('BookCopy')
        outDate = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
        inDate = models.DateField(null = True)
        dueDate = models.DateField()
```

However, when I run the code, I got an error saying NameError, global name 'dueDate' is not defined.  I don't see any problem at all. What's wrong with my code? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
books = Borrowing.objects.filter(dueDate < today_date)
```

You're doing [filtering](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.filter) wrong. `filter` parameters should be [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4), not just comparisons or even lambda functions.  It should be

```
books = Borrowing.objects.filter(dueDate__lt=today_date)
```

Refer to [field lookups](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#id4) documentation for details why and how it works, and what are other options.